# WP the_content() is not displayed in single template for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, custom-post-type

I have this very weird bug with Word Press `single-posttype.php` template.
The template renders any fields but the WYSIWYG type.

So first it wasn't rendering `the_content()` so I created custom field to test and the template renders it if it's just a text area, text field, boolen or whatever. But as soon as the field is WYSIWYG and contains paragraphs, the field simply is not shown.

Basically I have `single-posttype.php` which has

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This post type supports editor.

`single-post.php` and other templates display everything correctly. Any ideas?

**UPDATE (workaround):**

So I didn't find any proper solution for this problem, that's why I had to come up with a workaround. Since neither `the_content()` function nor filter would render content text in my template, I used raw content through `get_the_content()` (which still contained html tags like `<h1>`) and applied `str_replace()` to add `<br />` instead of line breaks. In CSS I styled this content div the same way as paragraph, and got the same final look in the template.
Here's the code for content (based on example from php.net):

```
 $str = get_the_content();
 $order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
 $replace = '<br />';

 $newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);
 echo $newstr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try placing a `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` before your post type loop and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Andy! i tried this now. I also tried renaming custom post type, changing it from post to page type, using the_content() in and outside the loop..nothing works. Aslo get_the_content() works, but it dismisses the <p> and breaks when rendering text. When I used $content = get_the_content() and then echo apply_filters('the_content', $content), the text disappeared again. Hence, I think it's something with the particular the_content() function or its filter that just doens't want to render text...

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify in the arguments of WP Query your custom post type name. Because custom post type posts are not posts.

```
$my_query->query(array('post_type' => 'CPT_name', 'post__in' => array($p)));
```

[the_content is displaying nothing for a costum post type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228846/the-content-is-displaying-nothing-for-a-costum-post-type)